# Ajax requests triggered twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm doing an ajax call in rail to update a flag in my database.

For some reason, the request is done twice.

the only difference between the 2 calls in the log is this:     ​

```
Started PUT "/negotiations/groupprocurement_validation_toggle?id=1504" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-01-20 22:28:39 +0100
Processing by NegotiationsController#groupprocurement_validation_toggle as JS


Started PUT "/negotiations/groupprocurement_validation_toggle?id=1504" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-01-20 22:28:40 +0100
```

Processing by NegotiationsController#groupprocurement_validation_toggle as */*

So the difference is in the "as JS" or "as */*".

I have no clue what it means :(

here's the link

```
 <%= link_to truefalse(validation_status.validated_global, true), validate_global_negotiations_path(:id => validation_status), :method => :put, :remote => true, :id => "validation_#{validation_status.id}" %>
```

The Javascript

```
 $('a[id^=validation_]').live('click', function(){
        var line_id = $(this).attr('id').replace('validation_','');

        $.ajax({
            url: '/negotiations/gp_validation_toggle?id=' + line_id,
            type: "PUT",
        success: function(data){
          $('#validation_image_' + line_id).html(img_result);
                $('#container').prepend(msg_result)
                $('#flash_notice').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
          $('#validation_image_' + line_id).html('<img src="/images/loading_round.gif">');
        }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

and in the controller, I have

```
respond_to :html, :js, :csv
```

and

```
  def gp_validation_toggle
      @negotiation = Negotiation.find(params[:id])
      @negotiation.validated_global = !@negotiation.validated_global
      if @negotiation.save
        flash[:notice] = "Modification saved"
      else
        flash[:notice] = "Oops something went wrong"
      end
  end
```

what am I doing wrong?

thanks,
P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using delegate instead of live

Comment: So, it worked somehow. changed first js line to   $('#list').delegate('a','click', function(){
Now only 1 request, but none of the javascript gets executed :(. Any idea?

Comment: That happens because live() method allows event bubbling, but delegate() doesn't.